# Are there R packages or functions that can detect the bit depth (8bit, 16bit) of a TIFF image?

Tags: r, image

I have TIFF images that are either 8 or 16 bit. I want to plot their colormap, or histogram, in R. I have tried EBImage and imager. Both import the image fine, but EBImage produces a histogram with the range 0-1, and imager is more variable, as the range is from 0 to around ~250 (which makes me wonder whether it converts 16 bit images to 8 bits). In a nutshell, I am looking for a package or function that can detect the bit depth of an image and plot a histogram that represents that data. For 8 bit images I would expect to see a histogram with values 0-256, for 16 bits images a histogram with values 0-65536.

Thanks.

Comment: You would get a very good idea by doing `length(table(values)) > 256` (where `values` are the actual pixel values). If `TRUE`, then there are more than 256 discrete values, which means more than 8 bits were required to specify them.

Comment: @AllanCameron  This is really neat, thanks. It is a very good solution to my main problem, but I don't think it will work for the histogram (though this is another matter and maybe I should ask it in a separate thread).

Answer (score 1):

The TIFF file format IIRC contains the bit-depth value in the header.  There are several packates at CRAN which read tiff files with various options and capabilities, so I recommend you try them out. HEre are the obvious ones:

ijtff
readbitmap
rtiff
tiff